# Why jsp: tags are not parsed?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have this `login.xhtml` JSF page:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jsp:root version="2.0"
  xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html"/>
<f:view>
  <h:inputText value="#{userBean.id}"/>
</f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

Output HTML contains properly rendered `<input>` tag, but `<jsp:*>` are left untouched. Seems that JSF just didn't understand them. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your're using JSF 2.0 and the file has a `*.xhtml` extension. You're actually using Facelets as view technology, not JSP. Facelets is the successor of JSP. You cannot mix Facelets with JSP tags. Get rid of all `<jsp:>` tags, they are worthless and ain't ever going to work in a Facelets page. The JSP tags are only parsed when you name the file `*.jsp` which will be picked up by servletcontainer's builtin `JspServlet`. But since you're using JSF 2.0 with Facelets, you already have the `FacesServlet` for the job. Forget JSP :)

Here's how your XHTML file should look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:inputText value="#{userBean.id}"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Note that you'd like to put that input component in a `<h:form>`, but I bet that it'll be just a test example.

Also note that `<!DOCTYPE html>` is [perfectly legit](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) here. You don't need the XHTML doctype. Facelets will take care about setting the right `text/html` content type, `UTF-8` character encoding and so on.

#### See also:

- [JSF/Facelets tutorial in Java EE 6 tutorial chapter 4-9](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html)
- [JSF 2.0 tutorial at Coreservlets.com](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/)

Answer (score 0):

The JSP tags you use don't generate any HTML.

The contentType directive affects header, not HTML.

Comment: But why do they stay in my HTML output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate JSF, a common way is to point the browser to login.jsf or faces/login.xhtml. If you don't then the file is serves unparsed to the browser

Comment: He is seeing JSP tags unparsed, not JSF tags.